# Sci-fi anthology novel. Cover story is about a holy war in space. Also contained articles about writing advice

Tags: story-identification, books

The book has a blue cover, and the cover has what looks like a King holding a golden shield and his face and right arm are pointing left while holding the object with his left arm.

The book is a collection of short scifi stories from a set of books and it's a later volume between 10 and 20 something. If I recall correctly the book has the volume numbers in numerals.

The story in the cover has to do with a holy war in space, or something of the sorts, at least the cover is from the paperback edition of the book.

I think the man either had a crown or maybe a light shining from his back like those paintings of Jesus.

All I know is one of the many parts the book has in between stories are introductions and writing advice, this one has a particular article that advises against writing scifi fanfiction, I would really like to know the article name.

If anyone could find me the book I'd be relieved, at least I'd have a starting point, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never read the volume in question so I can't confirm any of the story points.  But this cover from volume 22 of the "Writers of the Future" series seems to be a close fit for your description of the cover art.
[image]

OK. The arms are transposed, and the thing he's holding doesn't seem to be a shield, although it kind of looks like one.

Edited to include:  Found the contents on line.

http://www.writersofthefuture.com/l-ron-hubbard-presents-writers-of-the-future-vol-22/

Best guess is that the article you're looking for is the one by Sawyer.

Comment: YES, this is it, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help.  If it is the Sawyer article it's kind of ironic given his authorship of the final episode(s) of "Star Trek: Continues", perhaps the ultimate in fanfic/fanfilms